# Remove the breadcrums on a theme W

Tags: themes, css

I am looking to remove the breadcrumbs at https://thescruffytrader.com/mark-up-of-a-forex-chart/ by using CSS

Any idea on this?

Comment: CSS questions aren't really covered here. You could try over on StackOverflow, but you may need to be more specific - there don't seem to be any visible breadcrumbs on your page.

Comment: You could try inspecting the elements with your browser to identify what CSS specifiers to use, and then set `display:none`. How you apply your CSS will depend on your site - some themes have a "custom CSS" area where you can paste it in; if yours doesn't, you can use a plugin or create a child theme to add your own CSS.

Comment: btw I don't see a breadcrumb on the linked page